# Get element in CSV file, make it an integer and add it to the beginning of the line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, csv

I have a CSV with hundreds of entries and I'm trying to do the following:

```
 1. Get the first element (decimal number, ex: 1.01)
 2. Remove the decimal part of the element (ex: 1)
 3. Add the new number to the beginning of the file
```

Example Input:

```
"1.01","China Town Grocery","OE"
```

Here's what I need the output to be:

```
"1","1.01","China Town Grocery","OE"
```

Right now, I've been using the following for/do command via command line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in (input.txt) do (echo "input.txt[0]",%a) >> output.txt
```

I know I need to change what I'm echo-ing out. But I don't know how to grab that value. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My bad. Removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Although you tagged this as [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), this actually looks like Windows [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

You won't be able to do what you want in a single line, so you will need to create a batch file.

Here is the batch file that I came up with:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
    CALL :GetNumber %%a
    echo "!num!",%%a
) >> output.txt

:GetNumber
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in (%1) do (
    set "num=%%a"
)
```

Put this code into `filename.bat` and run it in the same directory as your `input.txt` file.

This does several things:

1. Enables [Delayed Expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to allow some variable processing inside the `FOR` loop.
2. Uses a [subroutine](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) to process the current line
3. Set an environment variable to the number you're looking for (because batch doesn't have functions with native `return` statements)
4. Output the line as you wanted.

Comment: Nice. As a *nix hacker, batch scripts really make my eyes itch.

Answer (score 1):

If PowerShell is an option:

```
Import-CSV "input.txt" -Header A,B,C | select-object New,A,B,C | ForEach-Object { $_.New = [math]::Floor($_.A); return $_ } | Export-CSV -Path output.txt -NoTypeInformation
```